# Java 2D control scroll bar after drawing

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jpanel, jscrollbar

I have simple `canvas` for drawing using `JAVA 2D`. It is `JPanel` from `swing` components.

```
public class DrawingCanvas extends JPanel{
//....
     @Override
     public void paint(Graphics g){
     //....
     }
}
```

This drawing canvas have a size (for example 200x200), i will draw to in for loop and if it exceeds a height of 200 want to be added to the scroll bar.

How can I do this? Can you show me somebody some demo?

It is Java 1.8.

Comment: You need to add it to the viewport of a `JScrollPane` and override `getPreferredSize`

Comment: And override paintComponent instead if paint